# MapStruct fluent getters

Tags: mapstruct

Is there any support for fluent getters in MapStruct? It seems that inspection of methods is done by method name. And so with fluent getters that have no prefix, everyone method could seem like a getter.

Has anyone tackled this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MapStruct does not support fluent getters. The reason for that is that fluent getters means every single method without parameters that returns non void type.

However, if you have some kind of annotation or some kind of rule that you can enforce for fluent getters then you can have a look at the `AccessorNamingStrategy` and provide your own implementation.

Comment: Why is it a problem if every single method is considered? I explicitly say the fields I want right? So if I say field `foo` then the method `foo()` will be the accessor.

Comment: Because MapStruct does not look at fields ti decide what f methods are getters. Your example will only work in a subset of cases. If hou are mapping from an interface there are no fields to look at